# How to pass id on pagination link button on same php page without link change?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to pass value on php without refresh and link change:

```
$pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/demo-project/book?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

The above code create new url what I don't want, like this:
demo-project/book?page=2

I want When I click on link only the page id will go in php, like:

```
$pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" data-id="2">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

I tried this:

```
        $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" data-id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</button></li>';
```

Then index.php

```
if (isset($_POST['data-id'])) {
$dataid = sanitize($_POST['data-id']);
var_dump($dataid);
}



<script>
$('button').click(function addseries(e){
var i = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
 url: 'index.php',
 data: i,
 success: function(data) {
 console.log(data);
  }
});

</script>
```

Nothing is working I tried but this is not working.

I want to send id and then like to get the value in php

but I don't want to create link href with page number in url and then get page number in php.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Start by changing `data: i` to `data: { id: i }` in the $.ajax options, and also change the PHP to `if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
$dataid = sanitize($_POST['id']);
var_dump($dataid);
}` because 1) hyphens in a field name, I don't know for sure if that will work, so best to keep it simple, and 2) you didn't name the data variable in your AJAX request, it was just a number by itself. So PHP has no idea how to match it to a named POST variable. You must send it with the name that you want PHP to match it to.

Comment: Also, `$('button').click(function addseries(e){
var i = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id');` can be simplified to just `$('button').click(function(e){
var i = $(this).attr('data-id');`

Comment: P.S. Bad idea to post the AJAX back to index.php, as it might return all sorts of other content as well as just whatever you want to get back from the AJAX specifically. Better to send the AJAX to a separate script which just processes that specific request.

Comment: @ADyson How? Better to send the AJAX to a separate script which just processes that specific request.  I need to create new php file the get POST Value?

Comment: I think it's better that way. Then it doesn't get mixed up with the main HTML of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You must name the parameter in you request like data : {"id":id}

```js
$('.page-item').on("click",".page-link",function(){

  var i = $(this).attr('data-id');

  alert(i);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'index.php',
  data: {"data-id":i},
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
 });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" data-id="5">5</button></li>
<li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" data-id="6">6</button></li>
<li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" data-id="7">7</button></li>
```

Comment: I have modified my response. You can print pages along these lines:  `<li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" data-id="YOUR_DATA_ID">5</button></li>`

Then create   event as shown above